# Mapping a JMS JNDI Entries with Thorntail

Tags: thorntail

I need to map the following JMS configuration I currently run in WildFly with Thorntail:

```
 <jms-queue name="ExampleQueue" entries="queue/exampleQueue java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/exampleQueue"/>
```

I haven't found any example which defines "entries" but I need it for remote JMS Clients. So I have come up with this configuration which, however doesn't work:

```
thorntail:
  management:
    security-realms:
      ApplicationRealm:
        in-memory-authentication:
          users:
            bob:
              password: Password1!
        in-memory-authorization:
          users:
            jmsuser:
              roles:
              - guest  
  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        jms-queues:
          exampleQueue: {}
            entries: queue/exampleQueue java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/exampleQueue
```

Which causes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 18, column 11:
              exampleQueue: {}
              ^
expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 19, column 13:
                entries: queue/exampleQueue java ...
```

I'm a bit lost. Can you help me to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it *almost* correct. What you need is (only showing the Messaging part):

```
messaging-activemq:
  servers:
    default:
      jms-queues:
        exampleQueue:
          entries:
          - queue/exampleQueue
          - java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/exampleQueue
```

(I think `queue/exampleQueue` should perhaps be `jms/queue/exampleQueue`, but not totally sure.)

For a complete working example, you can see e.g. https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/messaging-remote

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried and it compiles. What I have tried next is to run the JMSClient (the same available in WildFly quickstarts) but I receive this weird error: "2019-04-04 14:42:15,763 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (default I/O-9) AMQ222216: Security problem while creating session: AMQ119031: Unable to validate user from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57248. Username: jmsuser; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable". Running the same client against the WildFly distribution works fine. Is there any SSL setting in Thorntail that could help?

Comment: I guess you already have a dependency on the `management` fraction?

Comment: Uh! Pardon I didn't know that was needed. Thanks a ton, it works!

Comment: Yea, SSL doesn't work without `management`. It still bites me from time to time.